# building a data frame with pandas out of a nested structure in python

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested, structure

I want to implement machine learning with a dataset a bit too complex. I want to work with pandas and then use some of the built-in models in skit-learn.

The data looks is given in JSON file, a sample looks like that below:

```
{
  "demo_Profile": {
    "sex": "male",
    "age": 98,
    "height": 160,
    "weight": 139,
    "bmi": 5,
    "someinfo1": [
      "some_more_info1"
    ],
    "someinfo2": [
      "some_more_inf2"
    ],
    "someinfo3": [
      "some_more_info3"
    ],
  },
  "event": {
    "info_personal": {
      "info1": 219.59,
      "info2": 129.18,
      "info3": 41.15,
      "info4": 94.19,
    },
    "symptoms": [
      {
        "name": "name1",
        "socrates": {
          "associations": [
            "associations1"
          ],
          "onsetType": "onsetType1",
          "timeCourse": "timeCourse1"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "name2",
        "socrates": {
          "timeCourse": "timeCourse2"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "name3",
        "socrates": {
          "onsetType": "onsetType2"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "name4",
        "socrates": {
          "onsetType": "onsetType3"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "name5",
        "socrates": {
          "associations": [
            "associations2"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "labs": [
      {
        "name": "name1 ",
        "value": "valuelab"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to create a pandas data frame that considers this kind of "nested data" but I don't know how to build a data frame which takes into account "nested parameters" besides of "singles parameters"

For example, I don't know how to merge "demo_Profile" which contains "single parameters" with symptoms which is a list of dictionaries of, in same cases single values, and in other cases lists.

Anybody knows any way to deal with this issue?

EDIT*********

The JSON shown above is just one example, in other cases, the number of values in lists would be different, as well as the number of symptoms. So, the example shown above is not fixed for every case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and easy way to flatten your json data is to use the flatten_json package which can be installed via pip

```
pip install flatten_json
```

I expect that you have a list of many entries which look like the one you have provided. Therefore the following code will give you the desired result:

```
import pandas as pd
from flatten_json import flatten

json_data = [{...patient1...}, {patient2...}, ...]

flattened = (flatten(entry) for entry in json_data)
df = pd.DataFrame(flattened)
```

In the flattened data, the list entries get suffixed with numbers (I added another patient with an additional entry in the "labs" list):

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| index   demo_Profile_age  demo_Profile_bmi  demo_Profile_height demo_Profile_sex demo_Profile_someinfo1_0 demo_Profile_someinfo2_0 demo_Profile_someinfo3_0  demo_Profile_weight  event_info_personal_info1  event_info_personal_info2  event_info_personal_info3  event_info_personal_info4 event_labs_0_name event_labs_0_value event_labs_1_name event_labs_1_value event_symptoms_0_name event_symptoms_0_socrates_associations_0 event_symptoms_0_socrates_onsetType event_symptoms_0_socrates_timeCourse event_symptoms_1_name event_symptoms_1_socrates_timeCourse event_symptoms_2_name event_symptoms_2_socrates_onsetType event_symptoms_3_name event_symptoms_3_socrates_onsetType event_symptoms_4_name event_symptoms_4_socrates_associations_0 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 0                98                 5                  160             male          some_more_info1           some_more_inf2          some_more_info3                  139                     219.59                     129.18                      41.15                      94.19            name1            valuelab               NaN                NaN                 name1                            associations1                          onsetType1                          timeCourse1                 name2                          timeCourse2                 name3                          onsetType2                 name4                          onsetType3                 name5                            associations2      |
| 1                98                 5                  160             male          some_more_info1           some_more_inf2          some_more_info3                  139                     219.59                     129.18                      41.15                      94.19            name1            valuelab            name2          valuelabr2                 name1                            associations1                          onsetType1                          timeCourse1                 name2                          timeCourse2                 name3                          onsetType2                 name4                          onsetType3                 name5                            associations2      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The flatten method contains additional parameters to remove unwanted columns or prefixes.

Note: While this method gives you a flattened DataFrame as desired, I expect that you will run into other problems when feeding the dataset into a machine learning algorithm, depending on what will be your prediction target and how you want to encode the data as features.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to get. I do not get why the outcome is two rows when it should be just one patient. I do not get why event_labs_1_name and event_labs_1_value are NaN in the first index. Besides, as you said, I will encounter some problems when encode the data, for instance when I use OHE.  Another fact I should state is that maybe one patient have 3 symptoms while other have 5 or 2 or whatever. Same thing with the lists e.g.,  someinfo1 would contain 1 value or more. thanks for the help!

Comment: I think I get the flattened data. You added a new patient to the data and patient #2 contains one more value of lab. This is what I wanted, but as you said I will get in trouble when I encode!

Comment: Yes exactly. I'll add that to the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Consider pandas's [json_normalize](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html). However, because there are even deeper nests, consider processing data in pieces separately, then concatenate together with a fill forward on "normalized" columns.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with open('myfile.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read()) 

final_df = pd.concat([json_normalize(data['demo_Profile']), 
                      json_normalize(data['event']['symptoms']), 
                      json_normalize(data['event']['info_personal']), 
                      json_normalize(data['event']['labs'])], axis=1)

# FLATTEN NESTED LISTS
n_list = ['someinfo1', 'someinfo2', 'someinfo3', 'socrates.associations']

final_df[n_list] = final_df[n_list].apply(lambda col: 
                     col.apply(lambda x: x  if pd.isnull(x) else x[0]))

# FILLING FORWARD
norm_list = ['age', 'bmi', 'height', 'weight', 'sex', 'someinfo1', 'someinfo2', 'someinfo3', 
             'info1', 'info2', 'info3', 'info4', 'name', 'value']

final_df[norm_list] = final_df[norm_list].ffill()
```

Output

```
print(final_df)

#     age  bmi  height   sex        someinfo1       someinfo2        someinfo3  weight   name socrates.associations socrates.onsetType socrates.timeCourse   info1   info2  info3  info4    name     value
# 0  98.0  5.0   160.0  male  some_more_info1  some_more_inf2  some_more_info3   139.0  name1         associations1         onsetType1         timeCourse1  219.59  129.18  41.15  94.19  name1   valuelab
# 1  98.0  5.0   160.0  male  some_more_info1  some_more_inf2  some_more_info3   139.0  name2                   NaN                NaN         timeCourse2  219.59  129.18  41.15  94.19  name1   valuelab
# 2  98.0  5.0   160.0  male  some_more_info1  some_more_inf2  some_more_info3   139.0  name3                   NaN         onsetType2                 NaN  219.59  129.18  41.15  94.19  name1   valuelab
# 3  98.0  5.0   160.0  male  some_more_info1  some_more_inf2  some_more_info3   139.0  name4                   NaN         onsetType3                 NaN  219.59  129.18  41.15  94.19  name1   valuelab
# 4  98.0  5.0   160.0  male  some_more_info1  some_more_inf2  some_more_info3   139.0  name5         associations2                NaN                 NaN  219.59  129.18  41.15  94.19  name1   valuelab
```

Comment: Are you sure you want that structure? The JSON shows *Symptoms* as a long list. Otherwise you need 5 X names, 5 X associations, 5 X onsetTypes, 5 X timeCourse fields. Even more if structure differs.

Comment: I have always stressed to pandas OPs (even R and SQL) here on StackOverflow to keep data long as computation/processing is usually easier in that format than wide.

Comment: the thing is that when I use Machine learning methods, all of this columns mean the attributes and then the target should be assigned to this data. Therefore, the target is one column. Eventually, when predict, the outcome should be one value. I cannot predict in this case 5 values, and even more this JSON file I posted is just one example (if I want to make it in your way, now I would have 5rows per patient, but sometimes I would have 7, 10 or more or less because each patient is different and would have different symptoms.